# Can I create an app for iMessage? Such as a sticker app for the iOS iMessage app?

Tags: flutter, dart, imessage

I want to build an app for the default iMessage app on iPhone, I am curious to know if I could be built out with flutter? An iMessage Sticker app for example. Or is this only available through swift and Xcode?

Edit:
I am looking for an app to be built within the iMessage app of Apple’s iMessage app. Not an 3rd party messenger app. There are apps such as a sticker app that you can download from the App Store that then gets installed into Apple’s iMessage app. I just want to know if one can build this from Flutter, or can this build only be built from Xcode?

Answer (score -1):

I feel like your question is maybe not clear enough, but you can do a messaging app that works on ios.